# Objective-C/XCode: What class instantiation am I describing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

This UIElement appears when a user presses one of the hardware volume controls...the UI element is a black translucent square with rounded corners. In legacy versions of the Twitter app for iPhone, this element used to appear when a user would Follow, Unfollow, Retweet, etc. I would really love to use this element in my apps, can anyone let me know which element it is?

Best...SL

Comment: Could be anything -- the appearance of a widget is entirely controlled by the image used to produce it.

Comment: You're not describing a 'class instantiation'... You're describing user interaction with the UI.

Comment: You're not attempting to describe a [UIAlertView](http://cm-redmine01-data.s3.amazonaws.com/files/090319135501_ex3_2.png), are you?

Comment: Nope. This popup also exists in OSX. It appears when a user clicks Build and Run in Xcode, and the message either says "Build Succeeded" or "Build Failed" etc.

Answer (score 3):

It is a popup.  There are a few open source projects that will make implementing easier:

- https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD
- https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD

Answer (score 0):

That UIElement is a simple transparent `UIView`with a animation in it. The animation is like "fade in, show for a given time, fade out".